# How to encode an array of image, then post them?

Tags: angular, typescript, post, base64

I try to encode a list of image, then send them via a post request to a rest api.
Even after a lot of trials and fails, I can't mange to have the 'post' fired after the encodings

I'm not sure if it's relevant, but I should say that the app is an ionic app running on an android device

Here's the code. The blob list is null upon post firing, but I do get an encoded image in the log.

```js
    this.loadImages(lesObs[i].imagePath).then( async (blobList) => {
        lesObs[i].imageBlobs = blobList;
        this.http.post(this.url_post_one_observation, lesObs[i], { headers: this.headers })
        .subscribe(
        (result) => {
            console.log("upload done");
        }, (error) => {
            this.showErrorAlert("Erreur upload : " + error.status, error.message);
        });
    });


  private async loadImages(paths: string[]) {
    let lesBlobs :string[];
    paths.forEach(async (unPath) => {
      let img = await this.encodeImage(unPath);
      console.log ("img :" + img );
      lesBlobs.push(img);
    });
    console.log("returning les blobs");
    return lesBlobs;
  }

  private async encodeImage(path) {
    return this.base64.encodeFile(path).then((img) => {
      console.log("encoding " + path);
      return img;
    });
  }
```

Comment: It looks like at least code is missing. What errors are you getting?

Comment: No errors, but the blob list is null in the request. In the log I get    

returning les blobs  
encoding content://media/external/images/media/90692    
img :data:image/*;charset=utf-8;base64,/9j/4Wh4RXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAg ...."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you did not initialize `lesBlobs`, you just declared it. You will need to change it to `let lesBlobs: string[] = [];`

```
private async loadImages(paths: string[]) {
let lesBlobs :string[];
paths.forEach(async (unPath) => {
  let img = await this.encodeImage(unPath);
  console.log ("img :" + img );
  lesBlobs.push(img);
});
console.log("returning les blobs");
return lesBlobs;
```

}

In addition to that, your `lesBlobs` will most likely still return an empty array because the forEach is an async function. The easiest way is to change it to

```
for(const unPath of paths) {
  let img = await this.encodeImage(unPath);
  console.log ("img :" + img );
  lesBlobs.push(img);
}
```

Comment: yes that's it !  
I would have never guessed it, thanks a bunch :)