# Database query in loop returns only an empty array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, loops, knex.js

'requestingUserIds' is an array, with different ids. Each id belongs to a username in the table 'users'. That's why I want to loop, for each id in the array 'requestingUserIds', the corresponding username into the array 'requestingUserUsernames' and finally log the full array (requestingUserUsernames) into the console. But if I do it outside the then function, only an empty array is output, probably the array I initiated in the beginning.

When i log the array 'requestingUserUsernames' inside the then function in the console, the array gets outputted for each loop pass, but i only want to output the final array.

`````
requestingUserIds.forEach(userId => {
    db('users')
        .select('username')
        .where({id: userId})
        .then(rows => {
            requestingUserUsernames.push(rows[0].username);
         })
         .catch(error => console.log(error));
});
console.log(requestingUserUsernames);````
`````

Comment: because it is an async operation... you haven't the response back yet

Comment: That's what i assumed, but how do i solve this then?

Comment: Refer to my answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57058467/how-to-encode-an-array-of-image-then-post-them/57059353?noredirect=1#comment100644716_57059353

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
const requestingUserUsernames = await Promise.all(requestingUserIds.map(userId =>
    db('users')
        .select('username')
        .where({id: userId})
        .then(rows => rows[0].username)));
console.log(requestingUserUsernames);
```

Make sure it is in an async function

Answer (score 0):

```
requestingUserIds.forEach(userId => {
    db('users')
        .select('username')
        .where({id: userId})
        .then(rows => {
            requestingUserUsernames.push(rows[0].username);
            if (requestingUserUsernames.length ==  requestingUserIds.length) {
                console.log(requestingUserUsernames);
            }                                
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

This also worked, but im not sure if it is as clean as below.