# mapping a state property return empty array

Tags: reactjs

I'm writing a simple application which fetch data from xml files.
The fetchData function is okay and return an array that I store in my state.

But when I try to map this array it returns an empty array. So I can log my data but even when I try to get the lenght property, it returns 0...

You can see my code here:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { parseString } from 'xml2js';
import data from './data';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    parks: []
  };

  componentWillMount() {
    let { parks } = this.state;
    for (let key of data) {
      this.fetchData(parks, key.name, key.url);
    }
    this.setState({ parks });
  }

  fetchData = (parks, name, url) => {
    let free = '';
    let park = {};
    fetch(url)
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(xml => {
        parseString(xml, function(err, result) {
          if (result) {
            free = result.park.Free[0];
            while (free[0] === '0') {
              free = free.slice(1);
            }
          } else {
            free = 'no info avaible';
          }
        });
        park = {
          name: name,
          free: free
        };
        parks.push(park);
      });
  };

  render() {
    const { parks } = this.state;
    console.log(parks);
    const parkList = parks.map(({ name, free }) => <div>{name}</div>);
    console.log(parkList);
    return <div>{parkList}</div>;
  }
}

export default App;
```

console.log(parks) returns an array like this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Antigone",
    "free": "245"
  },
  {
    "name": "Arc de Triomphe",
    "free": "91"
  }
]
```

console.log(parkList) returns an empty array

Comment: it is because your fetchData is an async function. Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57209251/database-query-in-loop-returns-only-an-empty-array/57209669#57209669

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `fetch` is running asynchronously and `fetchData`will return before the actual fetch is finished. So `setState` is called before the `parks` object is filled and so the `render` function is called with the empty parks object. Also `console.log` is not running synchronously and for this you get the different outputs because of the reference to the object.

To fix this you have to wait for all fetches before calling `setState`

```
  componentWillMount() {
    let { parks } = this.state;
    const fetches = []
    for (let key of data) {
      fetches.push(this.fetchData(parks, key.name, key.url));
    }
    Promise.all(fetches)
       .then(()=>this.setState({ parks }));
  }

  fetchData = (parks, name, url) => {
    let free = '';
    let park = {};
    return fetch(url)
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(xml => {
        parseString(xml, function(err, result) {
          if (result) {
            free = result.park.Free[0];
            while (free[0] === '0') {
              free = free.slice(1);
            }
          } else {
            free = 'no info avaible';
          }
        });
        park = {
          name: name,
          free: free
        };
        parks.push(park);
      });
  };
```

It's also worthy to have a look at `async/await` in Javascript. With this you can write your code a lot more readable and obvious.

Comment: Thank you so much dude. I just tried to reproduce the same result with async / await but it looks like performance is worse.

You said console.log is asynchrone but I find it weird that I can log parks (and see the lenght property of the object) but when i log parks.length it returns 0. It's as if the value of "parks" used by "console.log(parks.lenght)" is prior to the one used by "console.log(parks)". Furthermore I can see my fetches with my react dev tools... Strange.... 

All this confused me but I think I understood the logic of promises and async / await in this example