# How to deal with a loop of promises dependant on another promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I'm new to JavaScript and I'm having trouble with promises.
I'm using cloudscraper to retrieve a webpage's html to scrape data from. I have a simple function - getData() - which calls cloudscraper.get() and passes the html to the extract() function, which is responsible for scraping data.
This is the working code:

```
const getData = function(pageUrl) {
  var data;
  return cloudscraper.get(pageUrl)
    .then(function(html) {
      data = extract(html);
      return data;  
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      // handle error
    })
}
```

The "data" object returned contains an array of URLs I want to connect to, in order to retrieve other information. That information has to be stored in the same data object. So I want to call cloudscraper.get() method again for each URL contained in the array.
I've tried the code below:

```
const getData = function(pageUrl) {
  var data;
  // first cloudscraper call:
  // retrieve main html
  return cloudscraper.get(pageUrl)
    .then(function(html) {
      // scrape data from it
      data = extract(html);
      for (let i = 0; i < data.array.length; ++i) {
        // for each URL scraped, call cloudscraper
        // to retrieve other data
        return cloudscraper.get(data.array[i])
          .then(function(newHtml) {
            // get other data with cheerio
            // and stores it in the same array
            data.array[i] = getNewData(newHtml);
          })
          .catch(function(err) {
            // handle error
          }) 
        }
        return data;  
      })
    .catch(function(err) {
      // handle error
    })
}
```

but it doesn't work, because the data object is returned before the promises in the loop are resolved.
I know that probably there is a simple solution, but I couldn't figure it out, so could you please help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are `return`ing from the middle of the loop, which doesn't work. Collect multiple promises into an array and use `Promise.all`.

Comment: Check my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57209251/database-query-in-loop-returns-only-an-empty-array/57209669#57209669

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct way to write loops for promise.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24660096/correct-way-to-write-loops-for-promise)

Comment: If you want to use a for loop, it will be better to use **async/await**, this way you can avoid the **.then** promise chain.

Comment: Thank you all for the quick response. Could you please give me an example? I read the answers but I don't know how to adapt them to my case.

Comment: `Promise.all` would be much more efficient and would take a fraction of the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be significantly simplified by using `Promise.all`, and `await`/`async`

If my understanding is correct, you are trying to execute the below steps:

1. Get original HTML
2. Extract some HTML (looks like you're after some more urls)
3. For each url extracted, you want to re-call `cloudscraper`
4. Put the results of each call back into the original data object.

```js
const getData = async (pageUrl) => {
    const html = await cloudscraper.get(pageUrl);
    const data = extractHtml(html);
    const promises = data.array.map( d => cloudscraper.get(d));
    const results = await Promise.all(promises);
    // If you wanted to map the results back into the originaly data object
    data.array.forEach( (a, idx) => a = results[idx] );
    return data;
};
```

Comment: Thanks. The code doesn't work out of the box because I didn't mention (for the sake of simplicity) that `array` is actually an array of objects, each with a `url` attribute, not an array of URLs directly. So I suppose I have to change the inner cloudscraper call to `cloudscraper.get(d.url)`

Comment: Yea, you have to specify that in the question in order for me to know that. But yes, as you've learned, you can just do `d.url` (or whatever property you're after). Please mark as answer or upvote if this helped.

Comment: It doesn't work, maybe I have to change something also in the forEach statement, haven't I?

Comment: Yes, the `url` fields don't get updated. Technically it's not an error, tough.

Comment: Ah. I see a typo. Fixed it. `promises[idx]` should have been `results[idx]`. Please remember to upvote

Comment: Thank you again for your help. Would a regular for loop be faster than the forEach?

Comment: You can use whatever iterator you need to. I just did forEach because I didn't need anything special. It really doesn't matter. The point is to just iterate over the results and set them in the other object. Indexes are guaranteed to match up, so you can use whichever method you are most familiar with.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to avoid these kinds of problems is to use [async/await](https://javascript.info/async-await), as suggested in the comments. Here's an example based on your code:

```
const getData = async function(pageUrl) {
  var data;
  // first cloudscraper call:
  // retrieve main html
  try {
    const html = await cloudscraper.get(pageUrl);
    // scrape data from it
    data = extract(html);
    for (let i = 0; i < data.array.length; ++i) {
      // for each URL scraped, call cloudscraper
      // to retrieve other data
      const newHtml = await cloudscraper.get(data.array[i]);
      // get other data with cheerio
      // and stores it in the same array
      data.array[i] = getNewData(newHtml); // if getNewData is also async, you need to add await
    }
  } catch (error) {
    // handle error
  }
  return data;
}
// You can call getData with .then().catch() outside of async functions 
// and with await inside async functions
```